# Prism Delegate Command on inherited viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, prism

Basically I got two classes:

1. `AppleViewModel : IAppleViewModel`
2. `AppleExtendedViewModel : AppleViewModel, IAppleExtendedViewModel`

I have a another public object: `JuiceViewModel Jvm` inside `AppleExtendedViewModel`.

In xaml there is a DataGrid which holds `AppleExtendedViewModels` within an Obersvable Collection. I have a command that resides in JuiceViewModel. That is used with `Command={Binding JuiceViewModel.CommandName}`.

Everything works fine when the JuiceViewModel is inside the ExtendedViewModel. But when I put it into the AppleViewModel, it no longer works. I thought it should work as well since the extended version inherits the AppleViewModel?

Comment: Please share enough code for us to reproduce the issue. It sounds like you moved something somewhere, and it's not working now. At that level of abstraction, the answer is "figure out what changed". You say the command is "inside" a viewmodel. Do you understand that that phrase isn't code, and gives nobody any concrete idea of what your code actually is? The runtime interacts with the code you wrote, not with your intentions.

Comment: So you move the property to the base class and then it no longer works? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @mm8 yes exactly

Comment: Prove your point with a code sample if you want someone to believe you then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve